# dynamically created buttons and event handlers

Tags: jquery, getjson

I have the function below that generates rows of buttons.

Is there a way of creating an event handler that would use the selected ID of each row(val.Id)?

Thanks

```
            $("#test").on("click", "input.select", function () {
            alert($(this).closest("tr").data("resultId"));
        });

        $("#btnSearch").click(function () {
            var searchTerm = $("#tbSearchField").val();
            $.getJSON('http://localhost:50151/api/principals/' + searchTerm, function (data) {
                var html = ""
                var sel = ""

                $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                    sel = val.Id
                    html += '<tr data-result-id="' + sel + '">'
                    html += '<td><input class="select" type="button" text="Select" value="Select"></td>'
                    html += '</tr>'
                });
                $(html).appendTo('#test');
            });
        });
```

Here is what the generated HTML looks like:

```
<table id="test" border="0" style="border: none; width: 100%; padding: 2px;">
<tbody>
    <tr data-result-id="1999860918">
        <td>
            <input class="select" type="button" value="Select" text="Select">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-result-id="1169565143">
        <td>
            <input class="select" type="button" value="Select" text="Select">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-result-id="1404344114">
        <td>
            <input class="select" type="button" value="Select" text="Select">
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you please explain a little more....what exactly you are trying to do

Comment: each row has a button...and each button needs to handle the unique ID of that row...I'd like to create one event handler that handles all these buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the id to the row, then get it from there.

```
html += '<tr data-result-id="' + sel + '">'
```

then, above your current code,

```
$("#test").on("click","td input[type=button]", function(){
    alert( $(this).closest("tr").data("resultId") );
});
```

remove the onlick attribute.

end result:

```
$("#test").on("click","input.select", function(){
    alert( $(this).closest("tr").data("resultId") );
});
$("#btnSearch").click(function () {
    var searchTerm = $("#tbSearchField").val();
    $.getJSON('http://localhost:50151/api/principals/' + searchTerm, function (data) {
        var html = ""

        $.each(data, function (key, val) {
            var sel = val.Id;
            html += '<tr data-result-id="' + sel + '">';
            html += '<td><input type="button" class="select" text="Select" value="Select"></td>';
            html += '</tr>';
        });
        $(html).appendTo('#test');
    });
});
```

Comment: I added the id to the row, pasted in the little event handler you wrote, removed the onclick, but the buttons now do nothing.  In firebug, I do see that the tr tags have the correct val.Id.

Comment: Oops, you're using inputs, not buttons.

Comment: oh should I change to a button?

Comment: Doesn't matter either way, as long as the selector is correct. i updated my code.

Comment: Ok I updated my code(see above) to reflect the changes, but it's still not working.

Comment: You missed the class here: `html += '<td><input type="button" text="Select" value="Select"></td>'` should be `html += '<td><input type="button" text="Select" class="select" value="Select"></td>'`

Comment: Ok, I added the class="select"...still no go.  I don't see any activity in firebug when clicking those buttons either.

Comment: by the way, what is .data("resultId") in the function you wrote above? -thanks

Comment: it's getting the value of the `data-result-id` attribute.

Comment: I edited my question above to include the HTML that is being generated.  Even when I copy/paste the code from your answer, I still get nothing.  I also don't see any activity in firebug.  It's as if the button is not being pressed at all.

Comment: You still have a naming problem. "Select" != "select"

Comment: "input.select" finds <input type="button" class="select" > The only capital "Selects" are the text and value properties.

Comment: sorry, i guess i mis-read it. i'll look over it again to see if i find anything

Comment: Are you using jQuery 1.7.2+?

Comment: nothing...I pasted it in and reloaded, and didn't see anything in firebugs console...

Comment: yeah I clicked on the buttons...should I be pasting it into a specific location? -thanks

Comment: It should be inside a document ready or before the closing body tag (after the table). You could actually just paste it directly into your firebug console if you want

Comment: running in the console, it returns this: Object[table#test]

Comment: The code in my answer should have worked then. Is all of this code inside of a `$(document).ready(function(){...})`?

Comment: I'd suggest not using that way of binding to ready, it was depreciated in jQuery 1.8

Comment: yes, though i suspect it won't make a difference here, the problem is probably elsewhere.

Comment: yeah no difference...i will have to look elsewhere

Comment: Your code worked...the #test table was inside an asp:UpdatePanel.  When I moved outside of the update panel, it works.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$("#btnSearch").click(function () {
            var searchTerm = $("#tbSearchField").val();
            $.getJSON('http://localhost:50151/api/principals/' + searchTerm, function (data) {
                var html = ""
                var sel = ""

                $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                    sel = val.Id
                    html += '<tr>'
                        html += '<td><input type="button" text="Select" value="Select" data-valId="' + sel +'"></td>'
                    html += '</tr>'
                });
                $(html).appendTo('#test');
            });
        });


$("input[type='button']").on('click',function(){
    console.log($(this).data("valId"));

});
```